# receive all udp packets on multicast

Tags: c#, sockets, udp, multicast, udpclient

i am using the c# UdpClient (client in code) to receive data on a multicast group.
In a while loop the follwing happens:

```
while(receiving)
    //First i check if data is available, polltime = 100ms
    if(client.Client.Poll(polltime, SelectMode.SelectRead))
    {
        //if data is present 
        data = client.Receive(ref remoteEp);
        ...
    }
    else
    {
        //100ms
        Thread.sleep(sleeptime);
    }
```

somehow i often miss packets (if there are more than one) that should be on the multicast and udp packet loss can´t be that much i guess.
Can the receiving be done better or does anyone know the problem)

Edit1:
The data that is sent are also by c# UdpClient and are byte arrays with the siz of 1024

Edit2:
In Wireshark i could see that the missing packets are not arriving, so the problem may be really udp packet loss?

Comment: Why are you doing the `Poll` and `Sleep`? Since `UdpClient.Receive` blocks until the next datagram is available, you should simply call it in a loop.

Comment: Then what would you do if there is no more data received? The socket would block forever.

Comment: To stop receiving data, you'd simply `Close` the UdpClient, wouldn't you? `Receive` would then terminate with an exception, i guess.

Comment: Yep it would be terminated and raising a socket exception, and we don´t want that.

Comment: Still the `Sleep` smells like packet loss. What will happen if during the sleep interval you receive more data than fits into your receive buffer? Packet loss is inevitable then. And maybe dumb question, but you know that polltime is microseconds, not milliseconds?

Comment: So what would be the alternative to sleep? also the sleep may not manipulate wireshark. Didn´t see that with the microseconds but i testet lots of different values.

Comment: I'm not saying that you *actually lose* packets on the receiving side, but your code makes it very likely. The alternative is to constantly `Receive` and terminate receiving by `Close`.

Comment: Don't be afraid of exceptions. The exception police have their phobias but you have a piece of code that doesn't work because you are wasting time sleeping while you should be reading. Just do a blocking read.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest the following implementation of the receive loop:

```
while (receiving)
{
    try
    {
        // block until data is present
        data = client.Receive(ref remoteEp);
        ...
    }
    catch (SocketException ex)
    {
        receiving = false;
    }
}
```